# A client error (UnauthorizedOperation) occurred when calling the StartInstances operation

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I just add a new instnace with ID instance i-b2117a3c. And I run those commands below.

`aws ec2 start-instances --instance-ids i-b2117a3c`

`aws ec2 start-instances --instance-ids i-1721b699`

But the result is like picture below:

[image]

```
A client error (UnauthorizedOperation) occurred when calling the
StartInstances operation: You are not authorized to perform this
operation.  Encoded authorization failure message: 
GJgQdcdGg4iYettPm2itv1SsHjBnkbssuu7re1vk6wcdh-5k1RHmsF09AlI8onB5TYvKZ4qJQ-Bt_-sXMXc5VUmKMAMXHy6DxyAXXkSRkamyOHrrBoat8hJNRUdyzXpWevtAukktDhg-K4uVDfDFtBJRc9PNA-9tg9ei5JUA_-uUMfmcphk3f72g94irJawvW4VJyWx6w-U-_wWUKJHUNL8eVWvq_3VYxWBdr4QhEZcpVAsFBObTglxheCoQGVGZ1UNw-B9B4nbldgD_rp-QUttAMQJFAwowZR5DEYXbhanV__Adjk1r_R5ZiBRSoe-MzZyjJlsHKM5NeJGl1SrgROltuiXy1fYL10feo3fd-WReGPp_GffEUqbUTaZmb4YvwX7xo6kkvreqMLNjO_7P63Bl8b1_MsneOVorlmER7E76qj0UBWcH7iiJa4e6DCQWzWZ1LUCMzHgqpiW_6s2v64_tvcrVF1U4pTWLUAvXd4NPEUjfDWFILqrhrh1Sp1ljrRGb8hD4E8U3HpGVeHXNiVJ2R60vsO0WJZiRiUoKzvTofQp1o-Ne4_MdburZJxhdb6lWpdPD63m6MFd5LeR8azbfWTOAXx2
```

May I have to add policy to i-b2117a3c. How to do it?

Comment: Where are you running the command?

Answer (score 1):

Your IAM user does not have privileges to start instances. Can you check the IAM policy for the user?

You can decode the error message by calling:

```
aws sts decode-authorization-message --encoded-message <encoded-message>
```

Comment: A client error (AccessDenied) occurred when calling the DecodeAuthorizationMessage operation: User: arn:aws:iam::973121498392:user/daas.svc is not authorized to perform: sts:DecodeAuthorizationMessage

Comment: The error message is clear. Have your IAM admin add necessary privileges to user daas.svc

Comment: I am IAM admin now. How to do it?